# Get the context around a line number in Bash from compressed file

Tags: macos, text, grep

I know that it's possible to search a line number (say, line # `139656504`) and return the context around it:

```
grep -n 139656504 -B 5 -A 5 file.txt
```

But when I used that on a compressed file it returned nothing:

```
zgrep -n 139656504 -B 5 -A 5 file.txt.gz
```

I'm on macOS Mojave.

Is there a way to get the context around that line with compressed files?

I made a test file (`test.txt`) that contains:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
test6
test7
test8
test9
testBB
test11
test12
test13
test14
test15
test16
test17
test17
test18
test19
test20
```

Compress the file:

```
pigz test.txt
```

Now if I run:

```
zgrep -n 10 -C 5 test.txt.gz
```

It gives me nothing... (I made sure that the line 10 would not have a number 10, otherwise, zgrep "searches" for a 10, not the line # 10)

If the line 10 would have been `test10` and not `testBB`, it would have worked. But this is not what I'm expecting.

Comment: `-n 139656504 ` doesn't search a line number, it prints the matches of pattern `139656504` with a line number.

Comment: That's what I understand too. But that's not what it says in `grep`'s manual: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html When looking at zgrep manual, it refers to grep manual. https://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep so I expected the `-n` to work, but apparently it's not doing what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
zgrep -n 139656504 -C 5 file.txt.gz
```

Notes:
`-n` means show line numbers in the output

`-C 5` means show 5 lines before and 5 lines after each line that satisfies the expression.

`139656504` is the pattern you are searching for.

Do `man grep` or `man zgrep` -- looks like all the command line switches work for either.

If all you need is to see surrounding lines of a specific line, you can do something like this:

```
gunzip -c file.txt.gz | sed -n "139656499,139656509p"
```

This means -- gunzip the file to stdout so you can pipe it, pipe it into sed which is an amazing utility, and sed here has been told to display line number 5 before and 5 after 139656504.

Comment: I've done it, but it shows nothing as an output... like it "runs" and then gives me an empty prompt. Like if it ran in the background and did nothing... I added an example in my question that shows what I mean.

Comment: I think the problem is what Freddy points out, which is to search a line number, grep is not enough since the pattern you have is telling it to look for that string, not the line number. Use sed or awk to search within a line number.

Comment: In the gunzip manual (https://linux.die.net/man/1/gunzip), it says that `zcat is identical to gunzip -c`. So it's still going to be slow on very large files.

Comment: If there would be a way to find a line number faster in large files (like finding something at line `139656504`, or more than million of lines), that would be even better. But so far, the way I understand this, one *has to* unzip the file before looking at the lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the content of a specific line number, you can use `awk`:

```
awk -v nr=10 'FNR==nr' file
```

or with line number prefix

```
awk -v nr=10 'FNR==nr{ print FNR":"$0 }' file
```

or with 5 context lines

```
awk -v nr=10 'FNR>=nr-5 && FNR<=nr+5{ print FNR":"$0 }' file
```

or

```
zcat file.gz | awk ...
```

for gzipped files.

Comment: On mac it'd be more something like this: `zcat < file.gz | awk -v nr=10 'FNR>=nr-5 && FNR<=nr+5{ print FNR":"$0 }'`. The thing that I'd like is this to run faster. I thought that using zgrep would make the process faster, but `zcat` is super slow on large files (> than 1 Gb).

Comment: This works too `gunzip -c file.gz  | awk -v nr=10 'FNR>=nr-5 && FNR<=nr+5{ print FNR":"$0 }'` and this `gunzip -c file.gz | sed -n "5,15p"`